# Generating MNIST numbers using LSTM-CGAN in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Inspired by [this article](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/12/24/conditional-gan-tensorflow/), I'm trying to build a Conditional GAN which will use LSTM to generate MNIST numbers. I hope I'm using the same architecture as in the image below (except for the bidirectional RNN in discriminator, taken from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09904.pdf)):

[image]

When I run this model, I've got very strange results. This image shows my model generating number 3 after each epoch. It should look more like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/586ead4b68d0eaa467cfe9015677cff28e36f070/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f37426f657951372e676966). It's really bad.

[image]

Loss of my **discriminator** network decreasing really fast up to close to zero. However, the loss of my **generator** network oscillates around some fixed point (maybe diverging slowly). I really don't know what's happening. Here is the most important part of my code (full code [here](https://pastebin.com/Pg0FMAsh)):

```
timesteps = 28
X_dim = 28
Z_dim = 100
y_dim = 10

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, timesteps, X_dim]) # reshaped MNIST image to 28x28
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, y_dim]) # one-hot label
Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, timesteps, Z_dim]) # numpy.random.uniform noise in range [-1; 1]

y_timesteps = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1), [1, timesteps, 1]) # [None, timesteps, y_dim] - replicate y along axis=1

def discriminator(x, y):
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE) as vs:
        inputs = tf.concat([x, y], axis=2)
        D_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(64)
        output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(D_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
        last_output = output[:, -1, :]
        logit = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(last_output, 1, activation_fn=None)
        pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)
        variables = [v for v in tf.all_variables() if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]
        return variables, pred, logit

def generator(z, y):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE) as vs:
        inputs = tf.concat([z, y], axis=2)
        G_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(64)
        output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(G_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
        logit = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(output, X_dim, activation_fn=None)
        pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)
        variables = [v for v in tf.all_variables() if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]
        return variables, pred

G_vars, G_sample = run_generator(Z, y_timesteps)
D_vars, D_real, D_logit_real = run_discriminator(X, y_timesteps)
_, D_fake, D_logit_fake = run_discriminator(G_sample, y_timesteps)

D_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_real) + tf.log(1. - D_fake))
G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_fake))

D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(D_loss, var_list=D_vars)
G_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(G_loss, var_list=G_vars)
```

There is most likely something wrong with my model. Anyone could help me make the generator network converge?

Comment: [These tips](https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks) may be useful even though they were written for simple GANs. Your issue is that discriminator learns so fast that it does allow generator to improve. This is a common issue. If your code has no obvious errors then that link should help you solve the problem.

Comment: I wonder if the generator needs more information to create meaningful digits? It seems like it's outputting very similar things at each row?

Comment: @JacquesKvam In some cases it's much worse than on the image above. The generator returns only straight vertival lines with a just few lines of noise on the top.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to improve your network architecture and training phase.

1. Remove the `tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)` from both the generator and discriminator. Return just the `pred`.
2. Use a numerically stable function to calculate your loss functions and **fix** the loss functions:

   D_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_real) + tf.log(1. - D_fake))
   G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_fake))

should be:

```
D_loss_real = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
              logits=D_real,
              labels=tf.ones_like(D_real))
D_loss_fake = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
              logits=D_fake,
              labels=tf.zeros_like(D_fake))

D_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(D_loss_real + D_loss_fake)
G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
              logits=D_real,
              labels=tf.ones_like(D_real)))
```

Once you fixed the loss and used a numerically stable function, things will go better. Also, as a rule of thumb, if there's too much noise in the loss, reduce the learning rate (the default lr of ADAM is usually too high when training GANs).
Hope it helps